# Mongoose .find fuction returns empty

Tags: node.js, mongoose

After some help on a previous question, I decided to re-start everything and look at every part of the code. When I run this query in robot3T it returns no issue.

[image: Robot3T query]

```
db.getCollection('episode').find({show_id: ObjectId("5d54fca24456f4ee892395b1")})
```

When I run the following code

```
const episode = new mongoose.Schema({
    show_id: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},
    show_b: {type:String},
    episode_no: {type:Number},
    title:{type:String},
    summary:{type:String},
    description: {type:String},
    link: {type:String},
    enclosureurl: {type:String},
    pubDate: {type:Date},
    author: {type:String},
    duration: {type:String},
    explicit: {type:String}
});

const EpisodeModel=mongoose.model('episode',episode);



router.get('/ep', (req, res) => {

    /* Pages.find({}, function(err, docs) {
       if (!err){ 
           console.log(docs);
           process.exit();
       } else {throw err;}
     });
   */
  EpisodeModel.find({}).exec(function(err, docs) {
    if (!err){ 
        res.status(200).json({
        docs
        })
        //process.exit();
    } else {console.log(err);}
    });

   });
```

instead of returning all the rows it returns this

```
{"docs":[]}
```

So something is totally wrong.

I have left a RAW JSON string below, which you can use to create your own JSON mongodb and insert into collection episode.

```
{
    "show_id" : ObjectId("5d54fca24456f4ee892395b1"),
    "show_b" : "rantshow",
    "episode_no" : 1,
    "title" : "episode 1",
    "summary" : "this is a test",
    "description" : "test",
    "link" : "test",
    "enclosureurl" : "test",
    "pubDate" : ISODate("2019-08-05T09:40:00.201Z"),
    "author" : "Radio Media PTY LTD",
    "duration" : "01:00:00",
    "explicit" : "yes"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the face of it, your query looks like it should work. Does it work when you try running it outside of mongoose? (For example, in Studio3T or via the CLI)

Mongoose may be getting confused because your show_id looks like an ObjectId, but is specified as a string in your schema. This sometimes happens because Mongoose, by default, converts strings to ObjectIds when it needs to (So that you don't have to manually do it).

I assume this is stored as a relational reference to a show document. If that is the case, then you should change your schema as follows:

```
const episode = new mongoose.Schema({
    show_id:{type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'show'},
    ...
});
```

The `ref` property should be whatever you have registered the show schema model as. For example, your episode schema above has used the term 'episode'.

You may need to update the episode document in the database to ensure it stores an ObjectId instead of a string.

**EDIT**

Your new implementation is almost correct. If you add one config to your episode schema, then it should work.

```
const episode = new mongoose.Schema({
        show_id: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},
        show_b: {type:String},
        episode_no: {type:Number},
        title:{type:String},
        summary:{type:String},
        description: {type:String},
        link: {type:String},
        enclosureurl: {type:String},
        pubDate: {type:Date},
        author: {type:String},
        duration: {type:String},
        explicit: {type:String}
      }, { collection: 'episode'});
```

Notice that at the bottom of this schema object, I have instructed that it should use the episode collection. Change this to whatever collection you're using for the episodes. I tested this in a local project and it works for me with the rest of your code.

Comment: Sorry that did not work - I am editing the question to show more code.

Comment: @RussellHarrower - Hey I updated my answer based on your new implementation code. I tested this out for you and it works for me! Let me know if you encounter any more issues.

Comment: Could you explain why that works? and should i always include  { collection: 'episode'} on a scheme?